# display tooltip on top of all html

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

How does one display a tooltip (from TW3) on top of all html?

I have a dialog (which is **not** a modal one) and I'm trying to make a tooltip to display at the bottom side of the textbox when hovering over it. But it is partially blocked by the dialog because of its position which is `absolute`.

Doing `tooltip { position: absolute; }` (or any other class like `.tooltip` (notice the dot in front of tooltip)) didn't work either. And It seems no one has ever asked this question before.

Documentation doesn't say anything about displaying a tooltip on top of all html either.

So how can I make the tooltip appear like if its  positioned absolute?

Comment: [`z-index:99999;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)?

Comment: Forgot to mention that `z-index` didn't work either. EDIT, I just tried it again after clearing IE cache (a few times) etc, and now it seems to be working :/

Answer (score 1):

something like this may be:
Make an event handler as following and attach it to the body of your html page

```
function hover (event) {
 var tooltip = '<div style="position: absolute;">Hi i am a tooltip</div>';
 tooltip.style.top = event.y;
 tooltip.style.top = event.x;
 tooltip.style.display = 'block';
 document.append(tooltip);
}
```